# i have 3 list views attached to single same base adapter

Tags: android

i have items for each list view now I have to delete items by clicking on it ,now how can i delete particular item of particular list view. because of single adaptor for 3 listviews I have an issue .so any suggestions please

Comment: the data you are passing in the constructor with the help of that you can remove what you need. Moreover lists are different there is no any issue in this

Comment: can u plzz provide any logic for that

Comment: You need to post some code what you have tried

Comment: I got it but now another issue that I have list view now am disabling items but i need to enable last two items\

Comment: apply logic according to position